# C# Dynamic Linq Where Clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq

is there a way to dynamically build a Where clause in LINQ?

Example... today I query my sql db, and only ServerGroup A has issues.  I return the fault codes for that group.  Works. However, tomorrow, ServerGroup A & B have issues. I do not want to manually change my LINQ query, but have it dynamically add the new ServerGroup to the WHERE clause.  Is this possible with LINQ?  I've done it with a Sql query.

Greatly appreciate the assistance.

```
        var query = referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(results => results.Field<string>("ServerGroup") == "A" ||
                             results.Field<string>("SeverGroup") == "B")
            .GroupBy(results => new
                {
                    FaultCode = results.Field<int>("FaultCode")
                })
            .OrderByDescending(newFaultCodes => newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode)
            .Select(newFaultCodes => new
            {
                FaultCode = newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode,
                Count = newFaultCodes.Count()
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `.Contains()`

```
var serverGroups = new string []{ "A", "B" }.ToList();

var query = referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(results => serverGroups.Contains(results.Field<string>("ServerGroup")))
        .GroupBy(results => new
            {
                FaultCode = results.Field<int>("FaultCode")
            })
        .OrderByDescending(newFaultCodes => newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode)
        .Select(newFaultCodes => new
        {
            FaultCode = newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode,
            Count = newFaultCodes.Count()
        });
```

where serverGroups would be dynamically generated.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Contains` in Linq query for SQL equivalent of `IN`.